How to Convert JSON Result to JSONB in a TypeORM Query Using PostGIS
I am currently working with a PostgreSQL database using PostGIS and TypeORM for a project. My entity includes a column defined as follows:
@Column("geometry", {
  transformer: new MultipointTransformer(),
  nullable: true,
})
directions?: Point[];

When I attempt to execute a distinct query, I encounter the following error:

error: could not identify an equality operator for type json

According to this GitHub note, PostgreSQL does not provide comparison operators for the json type, and it's recommended to use jsonb instead due to its operational benefits.
However, in my TypeORM setup, the query is automatically converted as follows:
ST_AsGeoJSON("orders"."directions")::json

I need to modify this to use jsonb instead:
ST_AsGeoJSON("orders"."directions")::jsonb

Is there a way to specify in the TypeORM query to cast the output of ST_AsGeoJSON directly to jsonb to avoid the error and properly utilize the distinct function? Any help or insight into how to adjust the query or the entity setup would be greatly appreciated.
